# How to cast a child instance from a parent instance in SQLalchemy with joined inheritance

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given a simple joined inheritance in SQLAlchemy, what's the simplest way to "cast" an instance of the superclass to it's subclass?

The obvious way is to check the discriminator on the superclass and then run a query based on the appropriate subclass. But it seems there ought to be a simpler way to do it.

Comment: What is it you're actually hoping to achieve. I don't understand why you would want to do the cast and I may have a better was to do it depending on what your actually trying to do.

Comment: I receive an id and load it via a parent query since I don't know in advance which subclass it is. I then want to convert that parent instance into an instance of the correct subclass so I can work with it (and its attributes and methods) directly.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to cast an existing parent instance but SQLalchemy does have ["with_polymorphic"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#basic-control-of-which-tables-are-queried) which can be used in a number of places to return glommed objects that have a combination of attributes in the parent and child based on the discriminator.

So, I added:

```
"with_polymorphic": "*"
```

to my parent's class `__mapper_args__` and now a query against the parent returns objects which have attributes and values of whichever child class it happens to be.

Is this the best and only way of doing this?